# How do I select the extended properties of an [Active Directory] object?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to pull a report of all our Active Directory accounts, include certain attributes/properties on each, and pipe it into a .csv file, so I can add formatting and filters (and so on like to) for management.

I've got a list of attributes that they want included (DisplayName, SamAccountName, Enabled, Created, AccountExpirationDate, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress), most of which are [extended properties of the Get-ADUser cmdlet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx).  I first tried to grab them like the default attributes, as below:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=somedomain,dc=tld" `
| select DisplayName, SamAccountName, Enabled, Created, AccountExpirationDate, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress `
| export-csv c:\DominAccountsPasswordInfoDump.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

...but that didn't work, as extended properties ["are only retrieved if they are specified in the -Properties parameter of the cmdlet"](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12031.active-directory-powershell-ad-module-properties.aspx#Extended_Properties), so I got a .csv with a bunch of blank columns.

Now my problem is that I don't know how to specify the `-Properties` parameter within my `select` statement, (I seem to get the below error message every way I try)

> Select-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Parameters'.

And on thinking about the `select-object` part of that, I'm starting to wonder if I need to define each user object I read in (assign it a to `$user` variable, or something), at which point I figured I should probably ask for help before mucking around any further.  Since searching Google and StackExchange didn't help, I'm asking here.

How do I select the extended properties of an AD user?  (Ideally, using the one-line script/PowerShell command I've got above.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do that in the Get-ADUser cmdlet.

Example:'

```
$Properties =
 @( 
 'DisplayName',
 'SamAccountName',
 'Enabled',
 'Created',
 'AccountExpirationDate',
 'LastLogonDate',
 'PasswordLastSet',
' EmailAddress'
 )

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=somedomain,dc=tld" -Properties $Properties | 
 select $Properties |
 export-csv c:\DominAccountsPasswordInfoDump.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The select will then exclude the default properties you don't want to export.

Comment: Worked brilliantly, thank you.  I think you saved me about an hour of banging my head against the wall, so much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome!  Seometimes you just need an example :).