# output file properties like filename, etc in powershell into a csv

Tags: powershell, csv

Im trying to output file properties like filename, date created along with MD5 hash for the entire system32 folder. 
using these commandlets in powershell from this solution [running two powershell commandlets into a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931154/)

```
 Get-FileHash C:\Windows\System32\drivers\ -Algorithm SHA1 |Select *,@{Label='VersionInfo';Expression={(Get-Item $_.Path).VersionInfo}} |Export-Csv c:\b.csv
```

I want the format in csv in separate columns for each file property.
Anyhelp wud mean a lot!

Comment: Do you want the file properties for each file in the `system32` folder?
If so then, you need to change the path to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\*` in order to select all files. The output will be in a `csv` format.

Comment: Yes, ur ryt I want output in csv format but dont want the versioninfo in a row, want metadata in separate columns, did change path as you'd written

Comment: I think that would have solved the issue for you. Further you can use the `recurse` parameter if you want to get into the sub directories also.

Comment: No, din achieve target yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\ | Select-Object Name,CreationTime,@{n='MD5';ex={(Get-FileHash $_.fullname).hash}}
```

Use `-Recurse` parameter if you want to get files from sub directories also:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\ -Recurse
```

Use `-File` parameter if you want to get only files and not folders:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\ -Recurse -File
```

Type the following command to get the list of all available properties:

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-Member
```

Comment: hello, thanx for the commandlets but need to export it all columnwise in csv format, cant do that getting multiple errors

Comment: Pipe it to Export-CSV cmdlet... what error are you getting

Comment: Yes, solved the issue , navigated to drivers and then exporting wasnt difficult atol!!

Comment: I have another problem @VincentK, I want the metadata and not just date created of the files in the directory. Cant get the output in that format, getting errors when I use this command

       Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\drivers  | select Name,CreationTime,Filedescription, Productname @{n='MD5';ex={(Get-FileHash $_.fullname).hash}}

Comment: Please read this article: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/02/06/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files/
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2015/02/22/filtering-files-by-their-metadata-extended-properties/

Comment: Vincent K these articles not really helping out, need something that is a single command as you'd earlier answered. Any help?
Downloaded microsoft script but doesn't work

Comment: found this but don't know if I can use it to my benefit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635379/how-do-i-select-the-extended-properties-of-an-active-directory-object

Comment: Also, can you please confirm if file metadata feature is available for powershell v4 onwards? I think maybe thats why it doesnt work.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2015/02/22/filtering-files-by-their-metadata-extended-properties/