# retrieve file properties along with MD5 hashes in a CSV file in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, hash, metadata

Im trying to output file properties like filename,product version, date created along with MD5 hash for the entire system32 folder.Any help?!
Using this

```
 Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\ | Select-Object Name,CreationTime,@{n='MD5';ex={(Get-FileHash $_.fullname).hash}}
```

I've used this solution [output file properties like filename, etc in powershell into a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947946/output-file-properties-like-filename-etc-in-powershell-into-a-csv/46948210?noredirect=1#comment80864726_46948210) but doesn't work! I need the columns to be of the order that I've specified here.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What error message are you getting? I am executing this command quite fine, and my CSV output is having those three properties listed.

Comment: It is working for me too. All the listed properties are getting displayed.

Comment: This only gives the creation time and MD5. I need the file metadata(things like product version, original name) along with MD5 not just creation time

Comment: Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\ | get-Member

-------- Pick up what properties you would like to include in your CSV file

Answer (score 0):

The link i posted does give what you want.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2015/02/22/filtering-files-by-their-metadata-extended-properties/

```
Get-FileMetaData C:\Users\vincent.k\Downloads\Program\ChromeSetup.exe | select Name,'Product Name','Product Version','File Description'

Name            Product name  Product version File description   
----            ------------  --------------- ----------------   
ChromeSetup.exe Google Update 1.3.31.5        Google Update Setup
```

[image]

Comment: As you can read in the help center, posting links without any contextual information is bad practice. Take a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Also keep in mind that code- and quotation blocks usually are better tools to show console outputs.

Comment: Hi, Vincent K, what about the hash? I want MD5 hashes too! That is not in the results that comes out in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You take directory too, use -file with get-childitem like this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\ -file | Select Name,CreationTime,@{n='MD5';ex={(Get-FileHash $_.fullname).hash}}
```